# Is it possible to find-or-create without locking or providing a future?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

I have the following case (simplified):

```
/* Register objects living
   and retrieve them on demand if the object is still alive on request.
   The interface have to be concurrency-safe.
*/
class Registry 
{
public: 

    void add( const std::shared_ptr<Thing>& thing ) 
    { m_index.emplace_back( thing );

    std::shared_ptr<Thing> find( ThingId id )
    {
       auto find_it = m_index.id( id );
       if( find_it != end( m_index ) )
       {
           // we can't remove the index safely (see http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/tbb_sa/help/index.htm )
           return find_it->second.lock(); // null if the object don't exist anymore
       }
       return nullptr;
    }

private:
   tbb::concurrent_unordered_map< ThingId, std::weak_ptr<Thing> > m_index;
};

// Concurrency safe too.
class Workspace
{
    Registry m_registry;
    std::unique_ptr<Thing> make_new_thing( ThingId id ); // not important 
public:

    std::shared_ptr<Thing> find( ThingId id ) { return m_registry.find(id); }

    /* The goal here is to either retrieve the existing object, 
       or to create it.
    */
    std::shared_ptr<Thing> find_or_create( ThingId id )
    {
        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
        if( auto thing = m_registry.find( id ) )
            return thing;
        return make_new_thing();
    }
 };

 // Concurrency-safe too.
 class Editor
 {
     Workspace& m_workspace;
     tbb::concurrent_unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Thing>> m_things;
 public: 

     void add_target( ThingId id )
     {
         m_things.push( m_workspace.find_or_create( id ) );
     }

 };
```

The context is important but let's focus on this part:

```
std::shared_ptr<Thing> find_or_create( ThingId id )
{
    if( auto thing = m_registry.find( id ) )
        return thing;
    return make_new_thing(); 
}
```

Here if simultaneous calls were made for this function, simultaneous calls to make_new_thing() could happen, which is valid if the Thing don't have the same id, but not if it doesn't. 
We can't remove ids from the Registry because of the concurrent_unordered_map implementation, so we have no way to check if the object is being created.

All this suggests that in this case, a synchronization mechanism is required. However, if I use something like a work queue, then I will have to provide a future, which currently is locking, but even with future.then() the caller could potentially wait a long time.

What I want is to avoid locking (with a mutex) if possible, and no future (in this particular case).

Do you see any way to do it without locking?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured that I could lock only when find_or_create() is called, not in other cases.

Comment: I'm undeleting this in case there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array or ring buffer of Things, and atomic operations. Built in atomic intrinsic or processor specific CMPXCHG assembly opcodes.

You would be sacrificing memory and essentially creating your own mutex and spin waits.

In the simplest implementation your ThingId would be index into the array. Your "find or create" would be a compare+exchange atomic operation where if the spot in the array is empty you'd exchange in an already created new object however if the spot was not empty you would delete the precreated new object or save it for the next call but that would require more atomic operations for concurrency of your object store.

Comment: ThingId have to be a UUID which imply that there is no way to use an array idx <=> id relationship.

Comment: @Klaim - Hashing and then modulus by the array size would be a proper transform to turn your UUID into a cyclical index.